# distribution of random variable and its pdf

Tags: probability, random-variables

This may sound overly simple but am I right in claiming that given a random variable $X$, $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution if and only if $f_X(x)$ is a even function? Because $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(-X\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(X\geq -x)$ for all $x$, which suggests the pdf if symmetric about the y-axis?
(I couldn't think of any counterexamples that will prove otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"...which suggests the pdf is symmetric..." -- Yep! In fact, it implies it. Assuming that $X$ is a continuous variable: as you noted, we have $\mathbb P(X \leq x) = \mathbb P(X \geq -x)$; hence, $\mathbb P(X \leq x) = 1 - \mathbb P(X \leq -x)$. (We can be sloppy about $\leq$ vs $<$ here due to the continuity of $X$.) Differentiating both sides shows that $f(x) = -f(-x) \cdot (-1) = f(-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a real-valued random variable $X$, it must not posses a pdf $f_X$.
Even if it does, a counterexample would be $f_X(x):=\begin{cases} 1 \,\text{ for } x\in(-1/2,1/2)\cup \lbrace 1 \rbrace, \\ 0 \,\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$
So let us presume the function $F_X: \mathbb R \to [0,1], F_X(x):= \mathbb P(X\le x)$ be differentiable and define $f_X := \frac{d}{dx}F_X$. Under this assumptions as you yourself pointed out correctly $F_X(x)=\mathbb P(X \le x) = 1- \mathbb P(X < -x) = 1-\mathbb P(X \le -x) = 1-F_X(-x)$. Differentiating both sides (and remembering chain rule for the other $-1$) yields $f_X(x) = -f_X(-x)\cdot (-1) = f_X(-x)$.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thanks for the correction